# One hour break between two lines of code in android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am building an android application and I want an hour gap between two lines of code,
I use thread.sleep() method with 1800000 seconds but it makes my application irresponsive and closed the execution.
Any suggestions or help would be beneficial for me.

Comment: Have you considered that you may be sleeping the main thread? Idling a thread for an entire hour sounds like a generally bad idea

Comment: Maybe you should use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager

Comment: What do you mean by a one hour gap? Do you want the rest of the app to run and then in one hour something to happen? Or you just want the app to sit there for an hour and then resume execution?

Comment: I think you are looking for https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Comment: @IvanWooll I want rest of the app run and something happen in one hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @GaneshPokale suggested above, [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) is the best solution for your case.

- Don't stop Main thread(=UI thread): Sleeping in the Main thread will stop your entire app, and it will lead you to [ANR](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr), which will make your app killed if your app is stopped more than 5 sec.
- In this case, you need to create another thread. WorkManager is one of the solutions for such cases, which need to wait a long time. You can also use AlarmManager or some other ways.

Comment: Ya it's a good solution of using another thread. Thnak you

Answer (score 0):

Try running the code on a different thread:

```java
class MyThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1800000000);
        } catch (InterruptedException err) {
            //handle interruption
        }
        System.out.print("world!");
    }
}
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Hello ");
        Thread t = new Thread(new MyThread());
        t.start();
    }
}
```

This will allow the main thread to continue running tasks while the second one is waiting in the background.

Comment: Thanks bro I think you gave me a better idea.